# Problems with multiplying a class variable with an instance

Tags: python, class, instance-variables

I am new to pyhton and also new to working with classes. I am working on the below problem where I want to multiply the class variable (raise_amount) by the instance salary. However, when i do this, I get None as output. I would like to get the salary amount per person multiplied by 1.04. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
class Person:
        
    raise_amount = 1.04
    
    def __init__(self, name, street_name, house_nr, post_code, salary): #:post_code, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.street_name = street_name
        self.house_nr = house_nr
        self.post_code = post_code
        self.salary = salary
        
  
    def street_name_and_house_nr(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.street_name, self.house_nr)

    
    def apply_raise(self):      # here is the code that seems to have problems 
        self.salary =  int(Person.raise_amount * self.salary)
    
    def street_name_and_house_nr_salary(self):
        return self.name + ' ' + str(self.salary)
        
prs_1 = Person("Mary's", 'Broadway', 304, '2526 CG', 10) 
prs_2 = Person("Jhon's", 'Longstreet', 304, '2829 AK',7) 
prs_3 = Person("Larry's", 'Chinstreet', 58, '3046 JP', 8) 

print(Person.apply_raise(prs_1))
print(Person.apply_raise(prs_2))
print(Person.apply_raise(prs_3))
```

This is the output i get when i run the code

```
None
None
None
```

Answer (score 0):

`apply_raise()` doesn't return the new salary, it just updates the salary attribute. So you should get that separately to print it.

```
prs_1.apply_raise()
print(prs_1.salary)
```

Other notes:

1. Conventionally the first argument to methods is `self`. Don't make up your own name (what does `lelf` mean?).
2. You should call methods using `instance.method()`, not `Class.method(instance)`. This ensures that the proper method will be used when the instance is in a subclass.